# Asp .Net Membership in multi tenant applications

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-membership, membership-provider, multi-tenant

How can asp .Net Membership be used in multitenant applications.

Lets take an example. I have a CRM application which has many user, and those user will have multiple customers.

Now in this case how my single .Net memberships DB help to authenticating/authorizing many other application.

Please note: I planing to keep several copies of application binary per tenant. and all those will be connecting to single CRM DB with unique ApplicationId from aspnet_applications

Comment: Are you using SimpleMembership or are you creating a custom Membership Provider?

Answer (score 0):

**SimpleMembership** use the Entity Framework code-first model. You can extend the user profile by going to **Models\AccountModels.cs** and modifying **UserProfile** to something like this:

```
[Table("UserProfile")]
public class UserProfile
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public int ApplicationId { get; set; }
}
```

In this example I added the property **ApplicationId** so that you can link the user to a specific application in other tables or databases.  If you want to setup a one-to-many relationship you can add the **UserId** to other tables to link it back to a specific user.

If you make any changes to the UserProfile class you need to delete any existing databases created by SimpleMembership in order for any changes to take effect.